# How to show Hibernate query result in Primefaces datatable?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, primefaces

It can be an easy problem, I have a native query with hibernate in my managedbean, my goal is to show it in a datatable of primefaces implementation.

```
       public List<User> retrieveAllUserName() {
            Transaction tx = null;
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            //Native Query
            Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select name from user");
            List<User> ls = q.list();
            System.out.println("query executed");
            for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("UserName:" + ls.get(i));
            }
        return ls;
        }
```

In my View:

```
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{userMBean.retrieveAllUserName()}">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Name
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{car.name}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

However i get the error:

> **"#{car.name}": Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String**

Edit:
**In addition, the native query can be changed to send more than one column.**

Thanks all.

Comment: Try `<h:outputText value="#{car}" />`.

Comment: Looks like you should also be getting some error in `retrieveAllUserName()` method.

Comment: @gurung, thanks it works but when i want to show both names and surnames using the native query then what should i do ? (there is no error)

Comment: Are they stored in separate fields or in one single?

Comment: @gurung they are different columns of a table in DB

Comment: You should not add multiple questions on one post. That makes it confusing. Try to make them separate posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning list of `User` objects:

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select firstname, lastname from user");
//when it's native query, returned list is a list of arrays, and each array is a row
List<Object[]> ls = (List<Object[]>) q.list();
//you should return list of User object from this method, so need to create one
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
for (Object[] row : ls) { // go throw each row
    User user = new User(); // instantiate a new User
    user.setFirstName((String) row[0]); // set it's first name
    user.setLastName((String) row[1]);  // set it's last name
    users.add(user); // add the User instances to the list "users"
}
return users; //return the list we created
```

In the above, you need to make some modification. Like in the query change the it have the actual column names in your table. And change the `User` object creation and setting of props to conform to how your `User` class is defined.

And then do something like this in the view:

```
<h:outputText value="#{car.firstName}" />
<h:outputText value="#{car.lastName}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL like this:

```
   public List<User> retrieveAllUserName() {
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        //Native Query
        Query q = session.createQuery("from user");
        List<User> ls = q.list();
        System.out.println("query executed");
        for (User u:ls) {
            System.out.println("UserName:" + u.getName());
        }
        return ls;
    }
```

Comment: my goal is to show the names or names+surnames in a datatable.