# Data Table Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm working with JSF Primefaces and I want to make a search and show results in  but results won't show, I'm doing this with Result type and had implemented like this in JSF 2.1 whith MyFaces tomahawk, but now with primefaces this doesn't work, here is my code

```
<h:form id="buscar_sucursal">
        <p:panel style="width: 800px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="5">
                <h:outputText value="Criterio: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="citerio" value="#{SucursalesBean.criterio}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="CVE SUCURSAL"></f:selectItem>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="NOMBRE"></f:selectItem>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Valor: " />
                <p:inputText id="valor" value="#{SucursalesBean.valor}"></p:inputText>
                <p:commandButton action="#{SucursalesBean.buscar}" value="Buscar"></p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
        <p:dataTable id="sucursalesTable" var="suc" value="#{SucursalesBean.sucursalesTable}">
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value=""></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Cve">
                <h:outputText value="#{suc.cve_sucursal}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Sucursal">
                <h:outputText value="#{suc.sucursal}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Domicilio">
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Contraseña">
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Accion">
                <h:commandLink value="Editar"></h:commandLink> / 
                <h:commandLink value="Eliminar"></h:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

And the code of my ManagedBean

```
public Result getSucursalesTable()
{
    return this.sucursalesTable;
}
public void setSucursalesTable(Result sucursalesTable)
{
    this.sucursalesTable = sucursalesTable;
}
public void buscar() throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    this.valor = request.getParameter("buscar_sucursal:valor");

    try
    {
        LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("LoginBean");
        Connection conn = loginBean.getConectar_db();
        //int id_empresa = loginBean.getId_empresa();
        ArrayList<SucursalesBean> al = new ArrayList<SucursalesBean>();
        st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = null;
        //ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT *FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente='"+request.getParameter("id_cliente")+"';"); // AND id_contribuyente='' AND id_empresa=''
        //if(request.getParameter("sucursales:id_sucursal") != null)
            //rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT *FROM sucursales WHERE id_sucursal='"+request.getParameter("sucursales:id_sucursal")+"' AND id_empresa='"+loginBean.getId_empresa()+"' AND id_contribuyente='"+loginBean.getId_contribuyente()+"';"); // AND id_contribuyente='' AND id_empresa=''
        if(getCriterio().toString() != null)
        {
            if(getCriterio().toString().equals("1"))
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT cve_sucursal,sucursal FROM sucursales WHERE cve_sucursal='"+this.valor+"' AND id_empresa='"+loginBean.getId_empresa()+"' AND id_contribuyente='"+loginBean.getId_contribuyente()+"';");
            if(getCriterio().toString().equals("2"))
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT *FROM sucursales WHERE sucursal LIKE '%"+this.valor+"%' AND id_empresa='"+loginBean.getId_empresa()+"' AND id_contribuyente='"+loginBean.getId_contribuyente()+"';");
        }
        this.sucursalesTable = ResultSupport.toResult(rs);
        //this.sucursalesTable = rs;
        //setSucursalesTable(ResultSupport.toResult(rs));

        /*while(rs.next())
        {
            //out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getString("sucursal")+"</td><td>"+rs.getString("cve_sucursal")+"</td><td>"+rs.getString("telefono")+"</td><td>"+rs.getString("e_mail")+"</td><td>"+rs.getString("calle")+"</td><td><a href='sucursales.jsp?accion=editar&id_sucursal="+rs.getString("id_sucursal")+"'>Editar</a></td><td></td></tr>");
            //setId_sucursal(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id_sucursal")));
            setCve_sucursal(rs.getString("cve_sucursal"));
            setSucursal(rs.getString("sucursal"));
            al.add(this);
        }
        this.sucursalesTable = al;*/
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
    }

}
```

I don't want to use serialized objects in order to use List type because I think it's to much code for doing something that supposed to be simple, even if this it's not the best aproach.

My doubt it's if Primefaces  has support for Result type or am I lost with this and maybe that's why this aproach isn't working.

Any help I really appreciate thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as you've converted a h:commandButton to p:commandButton. The first by default uses non-ajax request, but the latter uses an ajax request. If correct, you just need to tell the button which components to process during and update after the request:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{SucursalesBean.buscar}" 
                 value="Buscar" 
                 process="criterio valor"
                 update="sucursalesTable" />
```

Or use a non-ajax request:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{SucursalesBean.buscar}" 
                 value="Buscar" 
                 ajax="false" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question, I've tried with ajax="false" as you said by default is set to true, now refreshes the page after request and shows me next error:

Comment: /sucursales.xhtml @71,63 value="#{suc.cve_sucursal}": Propiedad 'cve_sucursal' no hallada en el tipo javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.ResultImpl

Comment: It seems SucursalesBean.sucursalesTable is of type Result which is'nt a Collection. The datatable can only show whats in a Collection, I believe. So I dont know whats easiest for you, but I would think you need some DTO Class to contain the results from the query, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597382/how-to-show-hibernate-query-result-in-primefaces-datatable

Comment: Hi Jaqen I've seen DTO Class container approach in lots of sites but the thing is that when you have an application too much modules these class containers grows a lot, also most of the examples I've seen are with view scoped beans wich consumes more resourses and my example it's with request scoped vean, I don't know if there's something to do, but the weird thing it's thas this was working with MyFaces but now that I've implemented with Primefaces don't, I will try to compact my code for doign this with DTO class and see what happened, maybe if I show you both codes you'll get a better idea

Comment: Hi and sorry for waiting to much time for an answer but after breaking my head for a long time, I just realised that prime faces don't support Result nor ResultSet type as most of the fórums says at least not in my versión, so in my code I replaced p:dataTable for h:dataTable and it Works, now the problema is with the p:commandLink to pass variable to reload the form for udating data, thanks in advance for helping me, I'll keep you in touch of any change